# Using HDF5 Thread Safe Library

Tags: c++, thread-safety, hdf5, hdf

I´ve got a question regarding the use of the HDF5 Thread Safe library.
I currently work with an instance of the HDF5 C++ library (static) that was compiled by a co-worker of mine using nether the `"HDF5_ENABLE_PARALLEL"` nor the `"HDF5_ENABLE_THREADSAFE"` options.

What I try to do is accessing an HDF file containing some data using multiple threads. The actual reading of the data doesn't need to be parallel.

My code currently looks somehow simplified like this:

```
// includes etc.

int main() {

  H5File t_file(FILENAME, H5F_ACC_RDONLY);

  thread t1(read_row, cref(t_file), 0);
  thread t2(read_row, cref(t_file), 1);

  t1.join();
  t2.join();

  return 0;

}

void read_row(const H5File & p_file, size_t p_row){

  double data[DIM_Y][DIM_X];

  try {

    DataSet t_dataset = p_file.openDataSet("/Group0/Set0");
    DataSpace t_dataspace = t_dataset.getSpace();

    hsize_t dims[2];
    auto status = t_dataspace.getSimpleExtentDims(dims, nullptr);


    hsize_t count[2] = { 1, DIM_X };
    hsize_t offset[2] = { p_row, 0 };
    t_dataspace.selectHyperslab(H5S_SELECT_SET, count, offset);

    hsize_t mem_dim[2] = { 1, DIM_X };
    DataSpace t_memspace(RANK, mem_dim);
    hsize_t mem_offset[2] = { 0, 0 };
    t_memspace.selectHyperslab(H5S_SELECT_SET, count, mem_offset);

    t_dataset.read(data, PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE, t_memspace, t_dataspace);

  }
  catch (...){
    cout << "Caught some exception" << endl;
  }
}
```

The code compiles and if I run the program most of the time everything goes well.
Sometimes however I get the following error message:

```
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.16) thread 0:
  #000: D:\Projects\CANoe\90\CMake-hdf5-1.8.16\hdf5-1.8.16\src\H5D.c line 358 in H5Dopen2(): not found
    major: Dataset
    minor: Object not found
  #001: D:\Projects\CANoe\90\CMake-hdf5-1.8.16\hdf5-1.8.16\src\H5Gloc.c line 430 in H5G_loc_find(): can't find object
    major: Symbol table
    minor: Object not found
  #002: D:\Projects\CANoe\90\CMake-hdf5-1.8.16\hdf5-1.8.16\src\H5Gtraverse.c line 861 in H5G_traverse(): internal path traversal failed
    major: Symbol table
    minor: Object not found
  #003: D:\Projects\CANoe\90\CMake-hdf5-1.8.16\hdf5-1.8.16\src\H5Gtraverse.c line 596 in H5G_traverse_real(): can't look up component
    major: Symbol table
    minor: Object not found
  #004: D:\Projects\CANoe\90\CMake-hdf5-1.8.16\hdf5-1.8.16\src\H5Gobj.c line 1139 in H5G__obj_lookup(): can't check for link info message
    major: Symbol table
    minor: Can't get value
  #005: D:\Projects\CANoe\90\CMake-hdf5-1.8.16\hdf5-1.8.16\src\H5Gobj.c line 333 in H5G__obj_get_linfo(): unable to read object header
    major: Symbol table
    minor: Can't get value
  #006: D:\Projects\CANoe\90\CMake-hdf5-1.8.16\hdf5-1.8.16\src\H5Omessage.c line 896 in H5O_msg_exists(): unable to release object header
    major: Object header
    minor: Unable to unprotect metadata
  #007: D:\Projects\CANoe\90\CMake-hdf5-1.8.16\hdf5-1.8.16\src\H5O.c line 1963 in H5O_unprotect(): unable to release object header
    major: Object header
    minor: Unable to unprotect metadata
  #008: D:\Projects\CANoe\90\CMake-hdf5-1.8.16\hdf5-1.8.16\src\H5Gobj.c line 1524 in H5O_msg_exists(): H5G__obj_get_linfo
    major: Object cache
    minor: Unable to unprotect metadata
  #009: D:\Projects\CANoe\90\CMake-hdf5-1.8.16\hdf5-1.8.16\src\H5C.c line 5281 in H5C_unprotect(): Entry already unprotected??
    major: Object cache
    minor: Unable to unprotect metadata
```

I suspect this occurs because the library itself is not thread safe in its current form.

My question now is:
If I would recompile the library using the --enable-threadsafe option would I then be able to work with a HDF5 file like I do above.
The library itself than should ensure that only one thread at a time is accessing a file (or is doing an API call) right?
And if I would recompile the library, would I still be able to use the C++ API?

I also tried to lock the API calls using a mutex but I still had some problems with it.

I would be very grateful if somebody here could give me an answer to my problem.
I hope I explained myself good enough. Sorry if this got a little long ;).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need to modify that file? If not, you can try to open the file in each thread, i.e., moving `H5File t_file(FILENAME, H5F_ACC_RDONLY);` into `read_row()`.

Comment: Anyway it might be dangerous to rely on the `--enable-threadsafe` configuration option. What does it actually mean? It will enable some locking mechanism in the HDF5 library source code. But this locking mechanism relies on a particular threading parading.Seemingly, it is Pthreads library, but you are using C++11 threads (which in likely built upon Pthreads as well). Mixing of different threading paradigms is very very fragile and is generally not recommended. For the same reason, HDF5 is not recommended to be used together with OpenMP.

Comment: @DanielLangr no I´m not gonna modify the file so moving the H5File Object to the thread might be a solution. I tried this in the example above and so far it seams to work. Sadly the crashes earlier occurred very unpredictably so I can´t be quite sure. But I think I might use the library in this fashion. Only one wrapper who is threadsafe and who does the actual IO. And this wrapper than can be used by multiple worker threads. I think this might work. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 3):

According to [HDF5 documentation](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/faq/threadsafe.html), it provides first level of thread-safety when compiled with --enable-threadsafe. But this is true only for the C library. High-level C++ library does not support thread safety. If you will try to run

```
./configure --enable-threadsafe --enable-cxx
```

you will get an error.
So, if you want to use C++ you have to compile hdf5 without "`--enable-threadsafe`" option and you should never access hdf5 library from different threads simultaneously. From my experience, it is better to access HDF5 always from the same thread in C++.

Some Linux distributions apply a patch that "fixes" this limitation by allowing both `--enable-threadsafe` and `--enable-cxx`, effectively breaking the C++ library. Newer version of libhdf5 even has an option `--enable-unsupported`, which will allow it without the patch. You will get random crashes using such an "**improved**" hdf5 package. So, check if you do not get such an "**improved**" library and recompile it manually if needed.